# Change cell if other cell contains text vba

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, worksheet

I used to have the following code and it used to work but for some reason it no longer works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim test As Range
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim i As String


    Set KeyCells = Range("AF3:AF5000")
    test = Target.Rows.Count


    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        For i = Target.Row To (Target.Row + (Target.Rows.Count - 1))
            If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 32) = "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 20).Value = "Closed"
            End If
        Next

    End If
End sub
```

Basically if there is data in any cells of column AF then the cell align with the information in column T would mark Closed. For example if AF65 <>"" then T65.value ="Closed"

Any idea why it no longer works or if there is another possibility for a macro?

Comment: I gather this is a Worksheet_Change event sub in a worksheet's private code sheet. That might have been something to include.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, I'll make the addition in the code.

Comment: What changed between when it worked and when it didn't work?  e.g. did you copy the code to another workbook (and put it in the wrong place), did you run some other event which disabled `EnableEvents` and you haven't yet renabled events?  Did you start working on a new worksheet (i.e. not the one with the Change event in it)?  etc, etc.

Comment: That's the thing, nothing changed at all... that's what is weird!! Would there be another code that can be written instead of this one?

Comment: Go to an immediate window and enter `Application.EnableEvents = True` - that may help.  Also, place a `MsgBox "Here"` prior to the `Set KeyCells ...` line - that will tell whether the event is being called.

Comment: What do you mean by go to an immediate window? I'm sorry I'm still new to VBA :-)

Comment: It now gives me an error: Compile error type mismatch and it highlights the i in the code: For i = Target.Row To (Target.Row + (Target.Rows.Count - 1))

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the redundant code and non-specific worksheet references. For example, a Worksheet_Change can be triggered when that worksheet is not the Activesheet; putting in Activesheet when it is not required only confuses the issue.

You also are not disabling events so your sub is going to try to run on top of itself.

This should be closer to what you are attempting to perform.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AF3:AF5000"), Target.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim trgt As Range
        For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Range("AF3:AF5000"), Target.Parent.UsedRange)
            If CBool(Len(trgt.Value2)) Then
                trgt.Offset(0, -12) = "Closed"
            Else
                trgt.Offset(0, -12) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next trgt
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If your original sub just 'stopped working' then put `Application.EnableEvents = True` into the VBE's Immediate window and tap [enter]. It is possible that your earlier code crashed with event handling disabled.

Comment: Awesome!! that works perfectly @Jeeped. Thanks so much :-) Have a nice day

Comment: I'm curious about `Intersect(Target, Range("AF3:AF5000"), Target.Parent.UsedRange)` - is there really any way that `Target` (i.e. the changed cells) could not be part of `Target.Parent.UsedRange`?  (E.g. does changing the colour of a column trigger a Change event?)  (You can tell I don't use events very often!)

Comment: @YowE3K - Deleting a full column or full row can throw a Worksheet_Change into conniptions without it. With .UsedRange, at least you are limiting the number of cells within Target to the worksheet's .UsedRange. I use a similar method in UDFs so that full column references can be passed into the UDF without processing every cell.

Comment: Ahh yes - a row deletion would cause every cell in column AF between the deleted row and row 5000 to become "changed" even if that extended beyond `UsedRange` - I learn (or remember) something new every day.  Thanks :)

Comment: Hey @ValS [if you find this answer solved your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please consider marking it as the accepted answer. It helps both you and the person who helped you :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png